# X86 Assembly Problems

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I'm attempting to get through a book on X86 that was written using examples from Visual C++ and Visual Studio. I'm trying to convert the examples for use with gcc. After a number of problems, I finally wound up with code that would at least compile, but now I'm getting segfaults. Here's the code:

assembly.s:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.section .text
.globl CalcSum
.type CalcSum, @function
// extern "C" int CalcSum_(int a, int b, int c)
CalcSum:

// Initialize a stack frame pointer
    pushq rbp
    mov ebp,esp

// Load the argument values
    mov eax,[ebp+8]
    mov ecx,[ebp+12]
    mov edx,[ebp+16]

// Calculate the sum
    add eax, ecx
    add eax, edx

// Restore the caller's stack frame pointer
    popq rbp
    ret
```

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int CalcSum(int a, int b, int c);

int main() {
   int sum = CalcSum(5,6,7);
   printf(" result: %d\n",sum);
   return 0;
}
```

I'm using `gcc -o execute test.c assembly.s` to compile. If I change all the 32 bit instructions to 64 bit (i.e. `ebp` to `rbp`) it will run but give completely random output. Could anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the first argument be at `[rbp+16]`?

Comment: I was actually wondering about that, are the calling conventions different between implementations? In the book I'm using, the stack is: 0 - Old EBP, 4 - Return Address, and 8+ - arguments.

Comment: 64 bit calling convention is totally different. Stick to 32 bit code, and compile as 32 bit (`-m32`).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh.aspx

Comment: Thanks all, I'll stick to 32 bit for now. I probably should have guessed.

Comment: The Windows 32-bit calling conventions are also different from the GNU 32-bit calling conventions. You need to find a resource that matches your platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, it's a matter of calling convention. 32-bit C functions follow the [`CDECL calling convention`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) in Windows and in Linux. In 64-bit Linux you have to use the [`System V AMD64 ABI`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI). The [`64-bit calling convention of Windows`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention) is different. There might be specifics to use functions of the operating system.

32-bit C (GCC):

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.section .text
.globl CalcSum
.type CalcSum, @function
// extern "C" int CalcSum_(int a, int b, int c)
CalcSum:     // with underscore in Windows: _CalcSum

// Initialize a stack frame pointer
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp

// Load the argument values
    mov eax,[ebp+8]
    mov ecx,[ebp+12]
    mov edx,[ebp+16]

// Calculate the sum
    add eax, ecx
    add eax, edx

// Restore the caller's stack frame pointer
    pop ebp
    ret
```

64-bit Linux (GCC):

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.section .text
.globl CalcSum
.type CalcSum, @function
// extern "C" int CalcSum_(int a, int b, int c)
CalcSum:

// Load the argument values
    mov rax, rdi
    add rax, rsi
    add rax, rdx

    ret
```

64-bit Windows (MingW-GCC):

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.section .text
.globl CalcSum
// .type CalcSum, @function
// extern "C" int CalcSum_(int a, int b, int c)
CalcSum:

// Load the argument values
    mov rax, rcx
    add rax, rdx
    add rax, r8

    ret
```